# d3js beeswarm with force simulation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to do a beeswarm plot with different radius; inspired by this [code](https://bl.ocks.org/hydrosquall/983d19b42a62fd1651c2942fe6cfcfbe/17b8802e7e1bcd7e860e10f07d2bc0a2e5a42088)

The issue I have, is that my point are offset regarding my x axis:
[image]

The point on the left should be at 31.7%. I don't understand why, so I would appreciate if you could guide me. This could be improved by changing the domain of x scale, but this can't match the exact value; same issue if I remove the d3.forceCollide()

Thank you,

Data are available [here](https://github.com/PDEUXA/sampledata/blob/master/static/data/qp_full.json).

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    function tp(d) {
        return d.properties.tp60;
    }

    function pop_mun(d) {
        return d.properties.pop_mun;
    }

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40},
        width = 1280 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var z = d3.scaleThreshold()
        .domain([.2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7])
        .range(["#35ff00", "#f1a340", "#fee0b6",
            "#ff0000", "#998ec3", "#542788"]);

    var loading = svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width) / 2)
        .attr("y", (height) / 2)
        // .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("Simulating. One moment please…");
    
    var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%"),
        formatNumber = d3.format(".0f");


    d3.json('static/data/qp_full.json').then(function (data) {
        features = data.features
        //1 create scales
        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(features, tp)/100])
            .range([0, width - margin.right])
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 0.1]).range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
        var r = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([0, d3.max(features, pop_mun)])
            .range([0, 25]);
        //2 create axis
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(20)
            .tickFormat(formatPercent);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .call(xAxis);
        
        var nodes = features.map(function (node, index) {
            return {
                radius: r(node.properties.pop_mun),
                color: '#ff7f0e',
                x: x(node.properties.tp60 / 100),
                y: height  + Math.random(),
                pop_mun: node.properties.pop_mun,
                tp60: node.properties.tp60
            };
        });


        function tick() {
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                var node = nodes[i];
                node.cx = node.x;
                node.cy = node.y;
            }
        }

        setTimeout(renderGraph, 10);

        function renderGraph() {
            // Run the layout a fixed number of times.
            // The ideal number of times scales with graph complexity.
            // Of course, don't run too long—you'll hang the page!
            const NUM_ITERATIONS = 1000;
            var force = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
                .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-3))
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height/2))
                .force('x', d3.forceX(d => d.x))
                .force('y', d3.forceY(d => d.y))
                .force('collide', d3.forceCollide().radius(d =>  d.radius))
                .on("tick", tick)
                .stop();
            force.tick(NUM_ITERATIONS);
            force.stop();

            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                .attr("cy", d => d.y)
                .attr("r", d => d.radius)
                .style("fill", d => z(d.tp60/100))
                .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
                    d3.select(this).style('fill', "orange")
                    console.log(i.tp60,i)
                    svg.append("text")
                        .attr("id", "t") 
                        .attr("x", function () {
                            return d.x - 50;
                        })
                        .attr("y", function () {
                            return d.y - 50;
                        })
                        .text(function () {
                            return [x.invert(i.x), i.tp60];  // Value of the text
                        })
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
                    d3.select("#t").remove();  // Remove text location
                    console.log(i)
                    d3.select(this).style('fill', z(i.tp60/100));
                });
             loading.remove();
        }


    })
})
```

Comment: At a glance force center is not useful here: the center of gravity for the nodes is not something you want to position: this will shift nodes so that their collective center if gravity is in the center of the chart: if you have only two nodes at 1% and 2% this would shift their center (1.5%) to the center of the chart where they shouldn't be

Comment: Thank you, Andrew, at a glance you are right. It's better, but I still have slight discrepancies; maybe due to the forceCollide.

Comment: Yes, you'll still have slight discrepancies: the force layout is a compromise between forces, the collision can conflict with the desired x value - one option would be to use a higher strength for the x force than for the y force.